# How can I access any files on NTFS partitions?

Tags: ntfs

I have just installed elementary OS Freya 0.3.1 (32-bit) on the "E" drive. I also have Windows 8 installed in "C" drive. I cannot access any of my "C" and "D" drive files. Can you suggest me methods which could help me access those files?

Comment: access from where? from elementary? Have you hibernated in windows?

Comment: problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

The *Possible* fixes:

1. Boot in to windows and **shutdown** completely.Then boot to elementary OS there the partition will mount in read-write mode automatically.

   (I too follow this when I got similar problem)

---

2. If you want to solve without doing shutdown,

   The simple way is using [ntfsfix](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ntfsfix)

   > ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems. ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk. It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

   Use `sudo fdisk -l` to identify `ntfs` partition

   Now run the command:

   ```
   sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda3
   ```

   **Note**: replace `/dev/sda3` with yours

---

**EDIT**:

If you are getting the same problem every time, the reason would be Fast Startup feature of Windows 8. Then the **permanent** solution would be : [**Disable Fast Startup in Windows 8**](http://itsfoss.com/solve-ntfs-mount-problem-ubuntu-windows-8-dual-boot/)